# % calculation in query with join and group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query  which counts pickups, and divides it by client ethnicity and category. It works, but I need calculate one column `'Pickups as % of Active'` which is total count of active clients in client  table (Active client is StatusID in (1,2,6) in Clients table, all other statuses count as nonactive)
My query looks like

```
SELECT
max(a.AgencyName)as Agency,
COUNT(PickupID)as Pickups,
( COUNT(PickupID)/(select  COUNT( c.ClientID) AS ActiveClients 
    FROM Clients c
    WHERE c.StatusID in (1,2,6) 
    GROUP BY c.AgencyID)) as 'Pickups as % of Active',
--SUM(CASE WHEN c.StatusID in (1,2,6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/ COUNT(PickupID) as 'Pickups as % of Active',
count (CASE WHEN p.CategCode = 'NB' THEN p.CategCode END) as NB
,count (CASE WHEN p.CategCode = 'IN' THEN p.CategCode END) as 'IN'
,count (CASE WHEN p.CategCode = 'CH' THEN p.CategCode END) as 'CH'
,count (CASE WHEN p.CategCode = 'PG' THEN p.CategCode END) as 'PG'
,count (CASE WHEN p.CategCode = 'BF' THEN p.CategCode END) as 'BF'
,count (CASE WHEN p.CategCode = 'PP' THEN p.CategCode END) as 'PP'
,count (CASE WHEN p.CategCode = 'SR' THEN p.CategCode END) as 'SR'

,count (CASE WHEN p.EthnCode = 'N' THEN p.EthnCode END) as Nat
,count (CASE WHEN p.EthnCode = 'A' THEN p.EthnCode END) as Asn
,count (CASE WHEN p.EthnCode = 'B' THEN p.EthnCode END) as Blk
,count (CASE WHEN p.EthnCode = 'P' THEN p.EthnCode END) as Pac
,count (CASE WHEN p.EthnCode = 'W' THEN p.EthnCode END) as Wth
,count (CASE WHEN p.EthnCode NOT IN ('N', 'A', 'B', 'P', 'W', '0') THEN p.EthnCode END) as Nat
,count (CASE WHEN p.EthnCode = '0' THEN p.EthnCode END) as Unknown
,count (CASE when PickupHispanic=1 then PickupHispanic end) as Hispanic 

FROM dbo.Pickup p join Agency a on p.agencyid = a.agencyid join Clients c ON c.ClientID = p.ClientID
where  PickupDate  between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-31' 
group by a.AgencyID 

WITH ROLLUP
order by 1
```

end it throws error

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Count results in an integer. And when you divide an integer by an integer it gives you an integer as a result.

Try casting your denominator as a decimal and it will give you a decimal as output:

```
 select 100 * COUNT(PickupID)/CAST(COUNT( c.ClientID) AS DECIMAL)
```

EDIT:

Okay, you've changed your code a few times which is quite confusing.

From what I can see at the moment, your error comes from the `Group By c.AgencyID` clause in the subquery. How about this:

```
( COUNT(PickupID)/(select Cast(COUNT( c.ClientID) AS DECIMAL) AS ActiveClients 
    FROM Clients c
    WHERE c.StatusID in (1,2,6) 
    AND c.AgencyID = a.AgencyID )) as 'Pickups as % of Active',
```

EDIT 2:

with the casting for a decimal result, and the casting for 2dp:

```
CAST(( COUNT(PickupID)/(select CAST(COUNT( c.ClientID) AS DECIMAL) AS ActiveClients 
    FROM Clients c
    WHERE c.StatusID in (1,2,6) 
    AND c.AgencyID = a.AgencyID )) as Decimal(10,2)) as 'Pickups as % of Active',
```

Comment: It shows `100.0000000000000000000` for every single agency which is can't be right

Comment: You get an integer when you divide 2 by 3?

Comment: Yep. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723215/why-does-sql-server-round-off-results-of-dividing-two-integers and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443672/integer-division-in-sql-server

Comment: @SimonC sorry for changing but it throws me error `Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Divide by zero error encountered.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation`

Comment: if i delete `WITH ROLLUP` it is calculating  but again not right it gives me only `0`

Comment: @SimonC I combined your statements and make it work :) However it still shoving % as long number with many numbers after comma how to show only 2 numbers after coma? I used `round` but it still shows like this `78.7900000000000000000`

Comment: You can cast the result again as a `decimal(x,2)` or `numeric(x,2)` where x is the number of total digits to show. The 2 (it can be any number) is the number of decimal places. I have shown it in an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Add your test to an expression that returns 1 if successful and 0 otherwise. Then add it up and divide it by your total to get the percentage.

You can use something like the following:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN c.StatusID in (1,2,6)
          and p.PickupDate  between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-31' 
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0
    END)
/ 
COUNT(PickupID)
as 'Pickups as % of Active'
```

EDIT: OK, I see that I was wrong the first time. You could get a count of active as a subquery instead:

```
SELECT
max(a.AgencyName)as Agency,
COUNT(PickupID)as Pickups,

COUNT(PickupID) / ActiveClients AS 'Pickups as % of Active',

count (CASE WHEN p.CategCode = 'NB' THEN p.CategCode END) as NB
,count (CASE WHEN p.CategCode = 'IN' THEN p.CategCode END) as 'IN'
,count (CASE WHEN p.CategCode = 'CH' THEN p.CategCode END) as 'CH'
,count (CASE WHEN p.CategCode = 'PG' THEN p.CategCode END) as 'PG'
,count (CASE WHEN p.CategCode = 'BF' THEN p.CategCode END) as 'BF'
,count (CASE WHEN p.CategCode = 'PP' THEN p.CategCode END) as 'PP'
,count (CASE WHEN p.CategCode = 'SR' THEN p.CategCode END) as 'SR'

,count (CASE WHEN p.EthnCode = 'N' THEN p.EthnCode END) as Nat
,count (CASE WHEN p.EthnCode = 'A' THEN p.EthnCode END) as Asn
,count (CASE WHEN p.EthnCode = 'B' THEN p.EthnCode END) as Blk
,count (CASE WHEN p.EthnCode = 'P' THEN p.EthnCode END) as Pac
,count (CASE WHEN p.EthnCode = 'W' THEN p.EthnCode END) as Wth
,count (CASE WHEN p.EthnCode NOT IN ('N', 'A', 'B', 'P', 'W', '0') THEN p.EthnCode END) as Nat
,count (CASE WHEN p.EthnCode = '0' THEN p.EthnCode END) as Unknown
,count (CASE when PickupHispanic=1 then PickupHispanic end) as Hispanic 

FROM dbo.Pickup p join Agency a on p.agencyid = a.agencyid 

join 
(select c.ClientID, COUNT( c.ClientID) AS ActiveClients 
    FROM dbo.Pickup p 
    JOIN Clients c on c.ClientID = p.ClientID
    WHERE 
        c.StatusID in (1,2,6) 
        and p.PickupDate  between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-31' 
    GROUP BY c.ClientID
) ActiveClientCounts
ON p.ClientID = ActiveClientCounts.ClientID

where  PickupDate  between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-31' 
group by a.AgencyID 

WITH ROLLUP
order by 1
```

Comment: right now it  shows `0` for all records in 'Pickups as % of Active'

Comment: Changed my approach. Basically, you already have the pickups. You just need to divide that by the active clients, which you can get with a subquery. I might have typed it wrong - just make yourself a query that gets what you want and add the SQL at the bottom.

Comment: `Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Column 'ActiveClientCounts.ActiveClients' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: And I was confuse you  with this line in subquery `and p.PickupDate  between '2012-01-01'and '2012-01-31'` It shouldn't be there

Comment: its throws error `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 34Invalid column name 'ClientID'.` doent like this line `ON p.ClientID = ActiveClientCounts.ClientID`