# Why does dividing 110 / 100 gives me the wrong answer in SQL?

Tags: sql, precision

```
declare @percent decimal(3, 2) = null;

set @percent = 110 / 100

select @agent_fee_excl_percent
```

This is giving me a 1.00 instead of a 1.1. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does SQL Server round off results of dividing two integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723215/why-does-sql-server-round-off-results-of-dividing-two-integers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are dividing an integer by an integer, which results in an integer (1), then you are assigning that to a decimal variable (1.00). You need to cast one of your values to decimal first, so that the result is decimal before being assigned to the variable `@percent`, like so:

```
set @percent = 110 / 100.00
```

...or...

```
set @percent = 110 / CAST(100 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
```

Comment: thanks, that was the problem. I needed to cast the 100 as decimal.