# Why are my CASE WHEN statements not dividing for one column of data when they work for another?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I'm trying to accomplish with this query is the structure shown in the image below. It's weird but I'm feeding this into some software where the output needs this format to work. Basically the "Prior %" items should calculate the year-over-year growth/decline. The calculation would take Revenue where Current_Prior = 'Prior' divided by Revenue where Current_Prior = 'Prior' - 1.

[image: Final Structure]

The way I've gone about this solution is to 1) use CTE to define Current vs Prior for each of the rolling sum metrics and 2) Calculate the Prior values and union them back to the data where Current_Prior = 'Current'.

The issue I'm running into is that my year-over-year calculations for revenue work perfectly, but when I repeat the exact same calculation for Total_Visits I wind up with the result below:

[image: Issue]

TEST1 is the division math and TEST2/TEST3 are each component of the calculation broken out. Each component calculates fine, but when you divide the two I get the output "-1" and I have no idea why. Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
WITH Time_Stage AS (

-----Current Year---
SELECT
    Date
    ,DateSkey
    ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(Day, Date, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 THEN 'Rolling 7D' ELSE NULL END AS Time_Group
    ,'Current' AS Current_Prior
FROM DimDate DD
WHERE
    1=1
    AND Date >= '2021-01-01'

UNION

SELECT
    Date
    ,DateSkey
    ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(Day, Date, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 1 AND 28 THEN 'Rolling 4W' ELSE NULL END AS Time_Group
    ,'Current' AS Current_Prior
FROM DimDate DD
WHERE
    1=1
    AND Date >= '2021-01-01'

UNION

SELECT
    Date
    ,DateSkey
    ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(Day, Date, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 1 AND 91 THEN 'Rolling 13W' ELSE NULL END AS Time_Group
    ,'Current' AS Current_Prior
FROM DimDate DD
WHERE
    1=1
    AND Date >= '2021-01-01'

UNION
-----Prior Year---
SELECT
    Date
    ,DateSkey
    ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(Day, Date, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 365 AND 371 THEN 'Rolling 7D' ELSE NULL END AS Time_Group
    ,'Prior' AS Current_Prior
FROM DimDate DD
WHERE
    1=1
    AND Date >= '2020-01-01'

UNION

SELECT
    Date
    ,DateSkey
    ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(Day, Date, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 365 AND 392 THEN 'Rolling 4W' ELSE NULL END AS Time_Group
    ,'Prior' AS Current_Prior
FROM DimDate DD
WHERE
    1=1
    AND Date >= '2020-01-01'

UNION

SELECT
    Date
    ,DateSkey
    ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(Day, Date, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 365 AND 455 THEN 'Rolling 13W' ELSE NULL END AS Time_Group
    ,'Prior' AS Current_Prior
FROM DimDate DD
WHERE
    1=1
    AND Date >= '2020-01-01'

    )

, KPI_Stage AS (

SELECT 
    DP.StoreName
    ,TS.Time_Group
    ,TS.Current_Prior
    ,SUM(TotalRevenue) AS Total_Revenue
    ,SUM(TotalVisits) AS Total_Visits
FROM FactDailyAggregate FDA
LEFT JOIN DimStore DP ON FDA.StoreSKey = DP.StoreSkey
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Time_Stage WHERE Time_Group IS NOT NULL) TS ON FDA.DateSkey = TS.DateSkey
WHERE
    1=1
    AND DP.StoreSkey = @Store
GROUP BY
    DP.StoreName
    ,TS.Time_Group
    ,TS.Current_Prior

), KPI_Stage2 AS (

--SELECT
--  KS.*
--FROM KPI_Stage KS
--WHERE
--  1=1
--  AND Current_Prior = 'Current'

--UNION

SELECT
    KS.StoreName
    ,Time_Group
    ,'Prior' AS Current_Prior
    ,(SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Group = 'Rolling 13W' AND KS.Current_Prior = 'Current' THEN Total_Revenue ELSE NULL END)
        /SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Group = 'Rolling 13W' AND KS.Current_Prior = 'Prior' THEN Total_Revenue ELSE NULL END))-1 AS Total_Revenue
    ,(SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Group = 'Rolling 13W' AND KS.Current_Prior = 'Current' THEN Total_Visits ELSE NULL END) 
        /SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Group = 'Rolling 13W' AND KS.Current_Prior = 'Prior' THEN Total_Visits ELSE NULL END))-1 AS TEST1
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Group = 'Rolling 13W' AND KS.Current_Prior = 'Current' THEN Total_Visits ELSE NULL END) AS TEST2
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Group = 'Rolling 13W' AND KS.Current_Prior = 'Prior' THEN Total_Visits ELSE NULL END) AS TEST3
FROM KPI_Stage KS
GROUP BY
    KS.StoreName
    ,Time_Group
)

SELECT
    *
FROM KPI_Stage2
```

Comment: Integer division. Multiply by `1.0` to convert to `DECIMAL` (or use an explicit `CAST`). I would vote to close as a duplicate, except I can't decide which of the dozens of questions to use -- for some reason none of those have been closed to refer to a "canonical" duplicate either. :P

Comment: This one then, I suppose. [Why does SQL Server round off results of dividing two integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723215/why-does-sql-server-round-off-results-of-dividing-two-integers)

Comment: If it was a snake it would've bitten me :). Thanks Jeroen for reminding me that integers don't magically turn into decimals.